# Выбрать наиболее часто встречающееся значение в столбце

Tags: django, база-данных, orm, sql

Как получить запись в БД с помощью ORM Django? Нужно выбрать значение, которое максимальное количество раз встречается в столбце.

Пример:

```
'd'
'a'
'd'
'c'
'a'
'd'
```

Нужно чтобы выдало значение 'd'.

Answer (score 1):

На SQL это будет так:

```
select val from tab 
group by val
having count(*) >= ALL(select count(*) from tab group by val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос.
Вот так на SQL:

```sql
SELECT user, COUNT(*) FROM tabl GROUP BY user;
```

Вот на Django ORM:

```
win_user = Visiting.objects.filter(activ = True).values('user').order_by().annotate(Count('user'))
```

Выдаёт:

```
[{'user__count': 7, 'user': 1L}, {'user__count': 6, 'user': 268L}]
```

Ну естественно добавив в конец [:1] всё вообще идеально становиться, а получив нужный id можно сказать что задача решена на 100%.

Всем спасибо.

Comment: Нашёл ответ на забугорном аналоге ХэшКода - stackoverflow)) Лиричная правда жизни...

Comment: Цитата. Ну естественно добавив в конец [:1] всё вообще идеально становиться

Не зная Django ORM, могу лишь догадываться, что это вывод первой строки. А если максимум достигается для нескольких значений?

Comment: Выведет один, первый, а кто будет первым это зависит от сортировки.